# asp.net-core 2.0 preview2 IdentityServiceOptions no longer exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

With the lastest build `asp.net-core 2.0 preview2` I am now getting an error that `IdentityServiceOptions` doesn't exist.

It was part of the namespace: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Service` but is no longer defined.

Does anyone know what the replacement for this is?

Comment: You can target your application to the 1.0.x sdk...there is an easy way to do it now https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnetSdkListAndDotnetSdkLatest.aspx

Comment: Sorry but I am really new with asp.net-core. Can you explain to me why I would target my application to 1.0.x sdk when I wan't to use the latest peview2

Answer (score 1):

As announced [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/253#issue-239057228), Microsoft's B2C emulator/OIDC development server (aka Identity as a service) won't be released as part of 2.0 RTM and thus was removed from the latest public preview.

Comment: Is there any documentations or examples how to implement authorization now with preview2

Comment: "authorization" is too vague. What are you trying to do exactly?